# What is the proper way to keep a repository of Python tools like classes and functions?

Tags: python

I have a `tools` directory in which I want to store some usable Python tools for future use.

For example:

```py
tools/
- __init__.py  # empty
- tool1/
--- tool_1.py  # has implementation of ToolClass1
- tool2/
--- tool_2.py
# ...etc
```

I want to easily import the tools to in my projects, so I added the `tools` folder to `PYTHONPATH`. My problem is that now importing a tool became quite complicated:

```py
from tools.tool_1 import ToolClass1

# whereas I would prefer using something like

import ToolClass1
# or
from tools import ToolClass1
```

What is the proper way of doing something like this? I read the [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) page but I did not find a direct solution.

P.S. I prefer not flattening the directory structure to have some order when more tools are added (unless necessary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the class-specific imports in your `__init__.py` file:

```
from .tool1.tool_1.py import ToolClass1
from .tool2.tool_2.py import ToolClass2
```

Which will allow you to do an import like

```
from tools import ToolClass1
```

Comment: This works well but then I have to update `__init__.py` after adding any class or file. Is there a way to do this automatically for all files and classes?

Comment: I can't imagine it being that much work ;-) I'm sure there's tools for that, but if you look at __init__ files for larger libraries (e.g. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/__init__.py) you'll see that it's quite convenient to have some say in doing this manually.

Comment: I did go for this solution eventually. Although I used `from file import *` in case there are few classes or functions in a file.

Answer (score 1):

Folders on `PYTHONPATH` should *contain* modules, but your `tools` folder *is* a module (since it contains `__init__.py`). Therefore you can't import anything from `tools` since it isn't recognized as a module. Put the folder `tools` is in on into `PYTHONPATH` and you should be much happier.

Comment: This still makes it quite complicated since I need to use: `from tools.tool1.tool1 import ToolClass1`